# How to install angular-json-editor with yarn which is available with bower package?

Tags: bower, yarnpkg

I want to install [angular-json-editor](https://github.com/rodikh/angular-json-editor). This is available with bower but I want to install it using Yarn packages.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
 yarn --modules-folder lib/ add angular-json-editor
```

to add `angular-json-editor` to folder `lib/`

Comment: I tried this but this added angular-json-editor in node_modules not in lib directory. How do i get it? I moved my project from bower to yarn so everything should update in@bower_components  i think

Comment: Use can use  flag `--modules-folder` add to folder